# datarow item in repeater doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm going through a repeater databound sub.

The data in the repeater can depend on what is selected in a dropdown, but some of my sql that is being used to display the data doesn't have a column `price` - how can I say e.g. "if exists "price" e.g.

I was trying:

```
If Not CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView) Is DBNull.Value Then
    'Do this
end if
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataItem` is always nothing/null on postbacks, it's only set after databinding. Values are maintained in `ViewState`(by default) across postbacks, so there's no need to maintain the datasource.

So you should use [`e.Item.FindControls(controlID)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.findcontrol.aspx) instead.

Comment: Off-related :  question : is there anyway to get the Current datarow (!) in `<span><%# Eval("PolicyName")%></span>` ? I mean I need the whole datarow ( I dont want OnItemDataBound) . in other words : `<span><%# dr ?   %></span>`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: why do you need the whole `DataRow` and why don't you want to use codebehind?

Comment: Because I have this http://i.stack.imgur.com/PEEA3.jpg ( rare case which ive encountered - and I'd hate to create 9 methods just for binding from dataset)

Comment: ( and I have a method which "digests the dr" and return normelized results ) so I want to write it inline the aspx ( instead of creating 9 onItemDataBounds)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You can use a single `OnItemDataBound` for all repeater. But apart from that, you could pass `Container.DataItem` to the method and cast it there to `DataRow` ( or maybe `DataRowView` which has a `Row` property).